# Tkinter focus_set() does not work on text widget

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am using Tkinter with python for a simple UI where I have a text widget and a button. When the button is pressed I want the cursor focus to be set on the text widget, using focus_set() method.

I don't understand why the focus_set() is not working in my code. I think it might be because my text widget is within a frame (frame1) and I cannot properly access this widget in my startPaus() method. Any ideas how I can fix the problem??

```
class TypingField(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent

        self.submit_tog = True
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.parent.title("Text Field")
        self.pack(fill = BOTH, expand=True)

        frame1 = Frame(self, width = 50, height =25)
        frame1.pack(fill = X, expand=True)
        self.scroll = Scrollbar(frame1)
        self.scroll.pack(side = "right", fill = Y)
        self.text = Text(frame1)
        self.text.pack(fill=Y)
        self.scroll.config(command=self.text.yview)
        self.text.config(yscrollcommand=self.scroll.set)


        frame2 = Frame(self)
        frame2.pack(fill=X, expand=True)
        self.submit = Button(frame2,text="Start Test")
        self.submit.bind("<Button-1>", self.startPause)
        self.submit.pack(fill=X)

    def startPause(self, event):
        if self.submit_tog:
            self.submit.configure(text = "Pause")
            self.text.focus_set()
        else:
            self.submit.configure(text = "Start Test")
        self.submit_tog = not self.submit_tog
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works on my machine.  Note that the focus is always on the Text widget for the code you posted, enter something to see this, because the focus is never set elsewhere, but in the code below it alternates between the Text widget and the Button to illustrate.

```
class TypingField():
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.submit_tog = True
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.parent.title("Text Field")

        frame1 = Frame(self.parent, width = 50, height =25)
        frame1.pack(fill = X, expand=True)
        self.scroll = Scrollbar(frame1)
        self.scroll.pack(side = "right", fill = Y)
        self.text = Text(frame1)
        self.text.pack(fill=Y)
        self.scroll.config(command=self.text.yview)
        self.text.config(yscrollcommand=self.scroll.set)

        frame2 = Frame(self.parent)
        frame2.pack(fill=X, expand=True)
        self.submit = Button(frame2,text="Start Test")
        self.submit.bind("<Button-1>", self.startPause)
        self.submit.pack(fill=X)

    def startPause(self, event):
        if self.submit_tog:
            self.submit.configure(text = "Text Focus")
            self.text.focus_set()
        else:
            self.submit.configure(text = "Button Focus")
            self.submit.focus_set()
        self.submit_tog = not self.submit_tog

root=Tk()
TypingField(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but for some reason this is not the case for me, the focus not on the text field. And by adding your line it still does not work.

Comment: Once I do self.text.focuse_set(), I check the focus by self.focus_get() == self.text and it does return True.  But the focus is not on the text field as I cannot type things straight away without selecting the text field. The focus is still on the button

Comment: I did more than add a line, as I hopefully also straightened out the frame disarray.  Copy and paste the code posted, run it and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks again for the reply, your code indeed worked and I spent ages trying to find the difference between yours and mine and actually my code works as it is. I found that it is because of my library import. I imported Button from ttk rather than using the Tkinter definition, which seems to be the reason why the focus is not set. Thank you for your help